# How can I disable selecting a particular date in a VCalendar Date Picker?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vcalendar

How can I make it impossible to select the same date for a Date Picker range ?

[image: here just like this - and choose the interval]

[image: and here one date is selected by double click]

And how to remove the option to select minutes?

[image]

I tried to remove the ability to select minutes using `:minute-increment="60"`

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatelly there does not seem to be a way to deactivate same day date range in the library.
Range rule does not specify any minimal duration : https://vcalendar.io/datepicker/api.html#datepartsrules
and disabling the first day has it is clicked make the final range invalid so the selection is aborted, see my example : https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-almeida-o7bhdw?file=/src/App.vue.

You might want to check other date picker library in Vue like https://vue3datepicker.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable minute selection, you can add a rule to fix them to 0. [See the documentation.](https://vcalendar.io/examples/date-picker-time-rules.html#VPSidebarNav)

```
<template>
  <VDatePicker v-model="date" mode="dateTime" :rules="rules" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const date = ref(new Date(2000, 0, 15));
const rules = {
  minutes: 0,
  seconds: 0,
  milliseconds: 0,
};
</script>
```

Comment: anyway, the option to select minutes remains (the field remains clickable)

Comment: Well, you juste have to use CSS `{ pointer-events: none; }` to make the select element unclickable.
See my code example https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-snowflake-6j2nuz?file=/src/App.vue